# Swapping functionality for left and right SHIFT keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome

I've a weird issue. On my macbook 2010, when I use Google Chrome, Command+Left Shift+T doesn't work as expected. I would expect it to reopen last closed tab, but, instead, it simply opens a new one. For what it's worth, same combo, but using right shift key works as expected - reopens last closed tab. Note that, aside from that, left shift key is working just fine. I tried a few extensions for Google Chrome that would let me change the keyboard shortcut, but none of them are using key-press recognition, and in none of them is right-shift, or it's variation that seem logical, are recognized. I'm on Yosemite 10.10.

Comment: Is it possible some third party app is messing with it? You could try it in safe mode and Chrome incognito window to see iCatherine is any difference. [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (version 10) can definitely do what you want. It also comes with Event Viewer.app, that you can use to see what the key you are pressing outputs. As a crazy last resort you could try to set the chrome shortcut to something else, then tell Karabiner to target chrome only and make cmd+shift+t output the new shortcut :/

Comment: To see if there is any difference*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swap mapping of left and right shift keys](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161599/swap-mapping-of-left-and-right-shift-keys)

Comment: @bjb not really.

Comment: On a system level, you can see your keyboard settings over here: system preferences -> keyboard -> shortcuts

A chrome extension may also be worth considering for getting control of your shortcuts. Not sure if the extension talked about on this page would enable you to override the default behavior or not: https://www.techjunkie.com/customize-chrome-hotkeys/