# What is blocking the Cmd-Shift-T in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, shortcut

Is there a way to see what program is picking up a keyboard shortcut on the Mac?

I can't restore a closed tab in Chrome (and neither in Firefox) by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and I am assuming that something else has bound itself to that shortcut and is swallowing it. I may be wrong, but is there a way to list all registered shortcuts or something like that? Or some other way to figure out what's going on?

Comment: Did something update itself recently - seems a bit of a coincidence to this one from a few hours ago - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304973/swapping-functionality-for-left-and-right-shift-keys